# Why doesn't this function infer its type correctly when retrieved from a mapped type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement an `authorize(user, action, object): boolean` function. The third argument, `object`, takes a dynamic type based on the action. For example, if `action = 'editArticle'`, then `object` is of type `Article`. The function seems to be typed correctly, since the code below in **authExamples.ts** compiles and errors in the expected places. But I can't seem to implement `authorize()` without resorting to casting. Is there a way to narrow or infer the type of the function looked up, so the call to it compiles correctly?

**authorize.ts**

```js
type Role = 'admin' | 'standard';
interface User {
  id: number;
  role: Role;
}

interface Article {
  id: number;
  authorId: number;
  published: boolean;
}

interface Operations {
  editArticle: Article;
  readArticle: Article;
  editUser: User;
}

type Action = keyof Operations;

type Permission<A extends Action> =
  (subj: User, obj: Operations[A]) => boolean;

type PermissionSet = {
  [A in Action]: Permission<A>;
};

const permissionAssignments: Record<Role, PermissionSet> = {
  admin: {
    editArticle: () => true,
    readArticle: () => true,
    editUser: () => true,
  },
  standard: {
    // All these correctly infer types
    editArticle: (user, article) => user.id === article.authorId,
    readArticle: (user, article) =>
      article.published || user.id === article.authorId,
    editUser: (subUser, objUser) => subUser.id === objUser.id,
  },
};

export default function authorize<A extends Action>(
  subj: User,
  action: A,
  obj: Operations[A]
): boolean {
  const permissions = permissionAssignments[subj.role];
  const permission = permissions[action];
  return permission(subj, obj); /* ERROR, ts(2345)
  Argument of type 'Operations[A]' is not assignable to parameter of
    type 'Article & User'.
  Type 'User | Article' is not assignable to type 'Article & User'.
    Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'Article & User'.
      Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'Article'.
        Type 'Operations[A]' is not assignable to type 'Article'.
          Type 'User | Article' is not assignable to type 'Article'.
            Type 'User' is missing the following properties from 
              type 'Article': authorId, published
  */
}
```

**authExamples.ts**

```js
const myAdmin: User = { id: 1, role: 'admin' };
const myUser: User = { id: 2, role: 'standard' };
const article: Article = { id: 100, authorId: 2, published: true };

// These correctly compile:
authorize(myAdmin, 'editArticle', article);
authorize(myUser, 'editUser', myAdmin);

// This correctly errors:
// Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter
// of type 'Article'.
//   Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type
// 'Article': authorId, published
authorize(myUser, 'readArticle', myUser);
```

Comment: Looks like a combination of [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) and [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581); the compiler's not good at this kind of reasoning.  If you're confident it's safe (and you have to be careful because someone can write the equivalent of `authorize<Action>(user, "editArticle", user)`) then use a type assertion and move on.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks so much! I figured my question might be a duplicate but I didn't know how to word it, I think I'll close this one now.